# Why Does VLC Media Player Uninstall When ZSNES Is Installed Through Terminal?

Tags: 11.10, uninstall, vlc

When I try to install ZSNES VLC is being uninstalled and the other way round. I don't want to make any changes to them whenever I do the installation.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Could you add the output of the installation of the zsnes ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install zsnes

Answer (score 1):

There is a ppa which has fixed this problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:smaxein/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install zsnes
```

Comment: It didn't work :-(

Comment: I don't understand, it worked for me.

Comment: Creepy :-( I just get a lot of errors :-(